# Convert json response (from google sheets API's 'spreadsheet.value.get ') into a pandas dataframe with correct column headers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-sheets-api

I have the following `.json` response that I have sourced from the `spreadsheets.values.get` method within the google sheets API

```
{'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
 'range': 'Sheet1!A1:D5',
 'values': [['Item', 'Cost', 'Stocked', 'Ship Date'],
            ['Wheel', '$20.50', '4', '3/1/2016'],
            ['Door', '$15', '2', '3/15/2016'],
            ['Engine', '$100', '1', '3/20/2016'],
            ['Totals', '$135.50', '7', '3/20/2016']]}
```

Within the json response above, the obvious column headers are `['Item','Cost','Stocked','Ship Date']` but the `.json` response appears to have these column headers included within the actual data records under the "values" label.

My intention is to read this .json response into a pandas df with the columns names sourced from the top row of "values" `['Item','Cost','Stocked','Ship Date']` . I am aware that you can use the pandas `json_normalize` method to flatten the "values" records but I haven't been able to separate the column headers as yet - can anyone help me filter the top row of "values" into a column header?

Suggested that I do the following:

```
response = {'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
 'range': 'Sheet1!A1:D5',
 'values': [['Item', 'Cost', 'Stocked', 'Ship Date'],
            ['Wheel', '$20.50', '4', '3/1/2016'],
            ['Door', '$15', '2', '3/15/2016'],
            ['Engine', '$100', '1', '3/20/2016'],
            ['Totals', '$135.50', '7', '3/20/2016']]}

sheet_values = response.get('values', [])

df = pd.DataFrame(sheet_values['values'],columns=sheet_values['values'][0]).drop(0)
```

The above code gets me the following error..

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your .json is called `response`, run:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(response['values'],columns=response['values'][0]).drop(0)
```

You don't need `sheet_values` code.

Comment: I like your idea but doing this gives me the following error...   `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Can you share your code? It's working properly here.